# Is there an easy way to automatically create a NuGet package from a Visual Studio 2015 project?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Before Visual Studio 2015, it was trivial to setup your project to automatically generate NuGet packages. Specifically, you did:

1. Add a **.nuspec** file to your project
2. **Enable NuGet Package Restore** in the Solution right-click context menu
3. Edit the project .csproj file and set the build property **`<BuildPackage>`** to true

And that was it!

However, starting from VS 2015, [MSBuild-integrated package restore has been removed](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/msbuild-integrated) and replaced by the new Automatic Package Restore. While these are all good news, it seems that setting the build property `<BuildPackage>` to true no longer triggers an automatic package build.

This is a major break of functionality! Is there a way to setup automatic builds of NuGet without using post-build events? Specifically, I'm looking for an MSBuild solution, as it forms the backbone of my build workflow.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how a build workflow relies on this, but staring from VS 2015, the output of a .xproj project is just the NuGet package, which suits your needs even more.

Comment: .xproj? That's the first time I've heard of it. There seems to be scattered information around the web regarding this project file type. Do you care to elaborate how you would go about creating or converting a C# project into a .xproj to produce a nuget package? That would be a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a move to Class Library Packages in VS2015 which makes it incredibly easy to create NuGet packages. I've [blogged](http://damien.dennehy.me/blog/2016/01/15/creating-nuget-package-3-easy-steps-using-class-library-package/) about this before, but essentially it's just a few steps. Note that this is just a RC1 at the moment and not a stable release yet.

1. Install the [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959) update to VS2015.
2. Open VS2015 and create a new Class Library Package project.

[image: Class Library Package]

3. Add your code to the library and configure the project.json file with any changes you may need. A [default](https://gist.github.com/DamienDennehy/7e304618e1a31ada609b) project.json file is used as an example.
4. Right-click on the project and select the Properties menu item. In the Build tab select “Produce outputs on build”. Build the project.

[image: Produce output]

You’re done. Go to the artifacts folder in your project, in my case “artifacts\bin\AwesomeSoft.TextConverter\Debug”.

You should see the NuGet package already created, and the folders targeting each framework specified earlier.

[image: Final nuspec]

Comment: Is this feature still around?  I've updated my ASP.NET and Web Tools to version 14.1.21111 and don't have a "Class Library (Package)" project type.  Not sure if it was renamed or removed, and all search results for Class Library Package are dated ~Jan 2016

Comment: No it's been removed. You need to add a post-build script in the project.json file or execute the "dotnet pack" command manually.

Comment: This seems to only be available for newer project types and not the older class library projects.

Answer (score 6):

Try OctoPack: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoPack/

Just add nuget package to your project.

If you want to build it every time you build release, add
to section `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|Whatever' ">`
next line:

```
 <RunOctoPack>true</RunOctoPack>
```

More information about finetuning can be found here: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative called NuPack :

[How-to-create-a-nuget-package-on-each-Visual-Studio-with-NuPack](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1190135/How-to-create-a-nuget-package-on-each-Visual-Studi)

It is a nuget package that automatically generate nuget package on build time.

Answer (score 0):

VS4MAc already supports this and you can get it as a extension for VS on Windows

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Build.Packaging